# Phonegap getPhoto not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

The documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) works great, but when I add the code to my application, the getPhoto part returns 'content://media/external/images/media/16053' and doesn't load the image into the img element, it uploads to the server fine. It's just on my application using onsen does it fail..

photo.html

```
<img src="{{ image }}" id="uploadImage">
```

app.js

```
$scope.onPhotoDataSuccess = function(fileURI) 
{
   console.log(fileURI);
   myNavigator.pushPage('photo.html', {animation : 'none'});

   $scope.image = fileURI;
}
```

I've tried adding a model,var attribute to the img element, but responds with null..

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-src instead of src in image tag , so that it will be in angular context.
Also I believe fileURI is in form of base 64..so you need to append to  data:image/png;base64 to the image source !

Comment: How would I implement this into my code? Why does the camera part work fine?

Comment: whats get stored in$scope.image ??